# JQuery UI breaks Flexslider 2 slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, flexslider

I have a big issue with my flexslider and jquery UI:

http://jsfiddle.net/YsvS3/

when i delete the include for jquery UI, everything works fine.

can someone help me ?

I include my slider as follows:

```
var rsjqfs = jQuery.noConflict();
        rsjqfs(window).load(function() {
          rsjqfs('#featuredslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlsContainer: ".headernewsnav",
            slideshow: true,
            controlNav: false,
            nextText: "",
            prevText: "",
            smoothHeight: true,
            animationLoop: true,
            animationSpeed: 500,
            easing: "swing",
            slideshowSpeed: 7000,
            start: function(slider) {
                // resize problem fix
                slider.resize();
            }
          });
        });
```